# Characters with accents from a MySQL DB showing correctly on PHP pages but not on HTML

Tags: character-encoding, character, diacritics

I have searched and searched and applied the obvious fixes but it seems I have another variant of the problem.  I have PHP pages and these display  what song is currently playing, what songs are coming next and last recently played on my web radio station, the info comes from mysql. The characters are displayed correctly on the php pages.  This is where it gets tricky, I also have HTML pages which load 2 div's from a php page so that the coming up songs also display on those HTML pages but there that's when the accents characters don't show correctly,  I have the correct meta tag in the header on those pages and have also used the .htaccess file trick (although I was not sure how important the location of the line in the file was so tried various places). I even opened my .htaccess in notepad++ to change the encoding to use UTF8 but no BOM. I even added a meta tag for UTF8 in the php page header and then the characters didn't work on php either, probably you're not supposed to. As you can see I spent a lot of time.  What's interesting the characters display correctly on iPad, it's on the PC browsers it doesn't work.  Maybe no one ever tried this before loading divs from php into HTML and have special characters too.  Sounds interesting anyway and if anyone is interested in having a think that would be great but it's not a vital problem just a nice to have fix.  The server side of my stuff is hosted on a hosting site

thanks

Comment: Some actual code examples would be useful.

Comment: ok but codes from which part of my set up though ?

Comment: Well well well it looks like it's a specific problem with loading divs from another page and the scenario below seems to be exactly my situation

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924122/load-kills-character-encoding

So that answers my question