# Umlaute are not being displayed in Chrome and Opera

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

The Problem: Chrome (Version 47.0.2526.106 m) doesn't display 'German Umlaute' regardless what I'm trying to do. Opera the same (34.0.2036.36)

However in Firefox (43.0.2) and Edge the 'Umlaute' show correctly.

Tried the following things:

- Cleared Browser Cache
- Saved all files with UTF-8 encoding from Sublime
- Checkt default character settings from hosting server
- Deinstalled 'Helvetica Neue' according to the hint here:
  www.productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome-de/eB_ljsQN2gw
- Header looks like the following:

  ```
  <?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="de">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  [...]
  ```

*Important to know is the fact that the affected text is located within another external .htm file which is loaded into a dynamically generated div via jQuery
like so:*

```
$(environment).load("infotxt/meadow-1-1.htm");
```

The intersting thing is that this is the only text that doesn't display the Umlaute correctly. 
I attatched an example picture of the site, the text I'm reffering to is the one in the upper right corner.
[Text with Umlaute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnBCg.jpg)

[Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnBCg.jpg)

Anyone encountered similar things?
Im thankful for support in this matter.

Cheers!

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Simply by **changing the extension** of the loaded document **from .htm to .php** together with my previous settings (as stated in the request/problem) did the trick for me.

You can find the link to the original answer here:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738713/4536968)

thanks to rslinger