# Why does jquery load() function ruins encoding and how to solve it?

Tags: jquery, encoding, load, charset

I am simply trying to refresh a div by this line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list').load(' #list');
});
```

The div has a php file that gets my DB data:

```
    include('getList.php');
```

but the otherwise perfectly working encoding gets screwed up after load.

I saw this old answer to a similar problem, but it doesn't help me:
[.load() kills character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924122/load-kills-character-encoding)

It seems like updating the div with jquery gets charset encoding of the header forgotten.

Any clue anyone? Thanks a lot.

Nothing solved it so far.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, though I haven't tried it. Using `setInterval` and then in `load()` add what to load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    setInterval(function(){
        
        $("#list").load('getList.php');
    
    }, 2000);
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. I finally solved it in a similar way, by 1) loading the php file into the div itself and 2) including the header charset in the new php file as well. :)